# Why isn't this recessed light working?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, dimmer-switch

I have 9 HALO (HLBSL6099FS35-4PK) LED recessed lights on an Eaton Universal dimmer switch. When I turn the switch on, 8 of the 9 lights turn on. Power flows from the switch, through the 8 working lights, and the wiring ends at the 9th non-working light. I have used a voltage tester and confirmed that power is going to the non-working light. I have tried the non-working light in another location and it turns on. I have tried taking other lights out so that only 5 lights are connected to power, but the last light in the series still doesn't turn on.

Any idea what might be going on or other troubleshooting steps I should take?

[image: light showing that power is reaching it]

Comment: If the problem is at this specific location, and the lights use separate drivers, (seems likely given visible cable)  and you are moving only the light, not the driver, you have a bad driver (or a bad connection TO the driver). Verify by swapping the drivers as well. Please [edit] to include the **specific model number** of HALO LED recessed light, which is an unfortunately non-specific description covering many different models.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the driver seems to have been the issue. I swapped it out and the light turned on, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

##### Neutral Problem

The NCVT specifically checks the *hot* (or in this case, *switched hot*) wire. It does not know or care about neutral. But without neutral, you don't have a complete circuit.

So carefully check the neutral wire at both 8th (last working) and 9th (not working) junction boxes.

Comment: Good thought. I visually inspected both neutrals and the connections look sound. Is there a meter or some other way that I could detect if this was the issue?

Comment: Use a multimeter. Should show ~120V between hot (when on) and neutral. In addition, neutral to ground (actual ground wire or metal junction box if it is grounded) should be 0V/continuous (near 0 Ohms). You can't just "connect neutral to ground" if you have a bad neutral (that is only done in the main panel) but it is a good way to test if neutral is good or not.

Comment: Visual inspection is good, @MarkW, but also, give each wire at each connection a good tug to make sure it doesn't come out of whatever connection device is being used. It's entirely possible for a wire to be in a wire nut, but not fully secured, and a tug will show that.

Answer (score 0):

Take one of the other lights and plug it into the end wiring. Looks like the power source or wiring for that end light might be bad. Forget about getting any meaningful information from those voltage testers, wonder sticks.

Comment: I've tried swapping out the lights to no avail. I can try swapping out the junction box, but I'll have to go to Home Depot before I can do that.